# Question on Quadratic equation

Tags: quadratics

Q- If roots of quad. Equation $x^2-2ax+a^2+a-3=0$ are real and less than $3$ then,

a) $a<2$

b)$2<a<3$

c)$a>4$

In this ques., i used $\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$ and then if $a$ will be $1,2$ only then the root will be defined but if we use $3$ then there will be only one root but in ques. Roots are mentioned. Is the right.

Comment: Hello, welcome to MSE! For your future reference, here is a tutorial on how to type math formulas using MathJax http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.

Comment: Please avoid abbreviations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here roots are $a \pm\sqrt{3-a}$.

So roots to be real,  $3-a>0 \implies a<3$.

And to satisfy second condition that roots be less than $3$, we see that

$a -\sqrt{3-a}<3$ iff $a<3$ and  $a +\sqrt{3-a}<3$ iff  $a<2$ ,

hence combining them all we get $a<2$.

Answer (score 0):

The discriminant of the polynomial is
$$
4a^2-4(a^2+a-3)=12-4a
$$
so you know that $12-4a\ge0$ and so $a\le 3$, which excludes (c).

For $a=0$, the equation is
$$
x^2-3=0
$$
and the roots are less than $3$, which excludes (b).

Now, how can you completely verify the assert (a)? The largest root of the equation is
$$
\frac{2a+\sqrt{12-4a}}{2}=a+\sqrt{3-a}
$$
and the condition is thus
$$
a+\sqrt{3-a}<3
$$
that's the same as
$$
\sqrt{3-a}<(\sqrt{3-a})^2.
$$
Since $a=3$ does not satisfy the inequality, we can reduce this to
$$
1<\sqrt{3-a}
$$
or
$$
1<3-a
$$
that's $a<2$.